# Jquery min date on two datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two date pickers `#plecare` and `#sosire`. I have managed to set the min-date for both date-pickers but i need `#sosire` to be always > `#plecare`
the HTML form`s are:

```
<div class="datepicker-wrap">     
    <input id="plecare" type="text" name="plecare" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="aa/ll/zz" />
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="datepicker-wrap">
     <input id="sosire" type="text" name="sosire" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="aa/ll/zz" />
</div>
```

The jQuery snippet from my theme-scripts is:

```
// datepicker
    tjq('.datepicker-wrap input').each(function() {
        var minDate = tjq(this).data("min-date");
        if (typeof minDate == "undefined") {
            minDate = +1;
                    }
   tjq(this).datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: 'images/icon/blank.png',
        buttonText: '',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeYear: false,
        /*showOtherMonths: true,*/
        minDate: minDate,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        closeText: 'Inchide',
        prevText: '&#xAB; Luna precedenta',
        nextText: 'Luna urmatoare &#xBB;',
        currentText: 'Azi',
        monthNames: ['Ianuarie','Februarie','Martie','Aprilie','Mai','Iunie',
        'Iulie','August','Septembrie','Octombrie','Noiembrie','Decembrie'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ian', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Iun',
        'Iul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        dayNames: ['Duminica', 'Luni', 'Marti', 'Miercuri', 'Joi', 'Vineri', 'Sambata'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dum', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Joi', 'Vin', 'Sam'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Du','Lu','Ma','Mi','Jo','Vi','Sa'],
        weekHeader: 'Sapt',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
            beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                var themeClass = tjq(input).parent().attr("class").replace("datepicker-wrap", "");
                tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').attr("class", "");
                tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass("ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all");
                tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass(themeClass);
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I accomplish the above so the min date for `#sosire` to be always greater that `#plecare`

Comment: You mean when #plecare changes value, #sosire's minDate should be changed to #plecare's date?

Comment: `#sosire to be always > #plecare` .So , What do you want? You want new mindate if a date is selected in `#plecare` ? If yes what will be the value of `minDate`

Comment: when #plecare changes #sosire must be greater than #plecare

Comment: @Runcorn exactely. ANd the value of minDate to be +1

Comment: [This little article](https://codeavenues.wordpress.com/2015/01/10/start-end-date-validation-in-jquery-ui-datepicker/) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand you need something like [this.](http://jsfiddle.net/nkw9wuq1/embedded/)

**jQuery**

```
    $("#from").datepicker({onClose:function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }});
    $("#to").datepicker({onClose:function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }});
```

**HTML**

```
<label>Start Date:</label>
<input id=”from”> </input>
<label>End Date:</label>
<input id=”to”> </input>
```

You can bound the start date to do not exceed from the end date. same for the end date to do not go beyond the start date. [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/nkw9wuq1/embedded/)

Answer (score 1):

save a backup of the last date, hookup a listener to the change events of the two inputs, when one fires check the other, if the date is invalid revert back to previous date and show some sort of error

```
var startDateBkup, endDateBkup;
$('#startDate').change(function(){ 

    var $this = $(this);
    var currdate = $this.datepicker('getDate'); 

    if(currdate > $('#endDate').datepicker('getDate')){

        $this.datepicker('setDate',startDateBkup);
        //put some notification

    } else {
        startDateBkup = currdate;
    }

})
```

And do the same for the end date, but reversed, not sure about all the nuances of that widget, so might have to reset some ui elements but logically that will handle what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` event of the later `datePicker` for manipulating the values,

```
onSelect : function () {
      var newDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      if($(this).prop("id")=="plecare"){
          //If plecare select event , set minDate for sosire
          $("#sosire").datepicker( "option", "minDate", newDate);       
          }
    }
```

#### And here is a [demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/337/)

Note:

if you want to add "**+1 day**" to `minDate` then you should use ,

```
var newDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
newDate = new Date(newDate.getFullYear(), newDate.getMonth(), newDate.getDate()+1);
```

I hope this is what you want.